# Rotating a matrix by n degrees in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I was asked in the interview recently to rotate the matrix by 270 degrees clockwise or 90 anti-clockwise. I answered by giving the solution for how to rotate it by 90 degrees clockwise. The solution is as follows:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def RoatateMatrix(matrix,n):
    res = deepcopy(matrix)
    for x in range(0,n):
        for y in range(n-1,-1,-1):
            res[x][n-y-1] = matrix[y][x]
    return res

n = 3
matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print RotateMatrix(matrix,n)

#[[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
```

Is there any way to twist the above code to rotate it by 270 degree clockwise? Please also suggest in place alternative. Thanks.

Comment: So, you can rotate it by 90 degrees, and you're asking how to rotate it by 270 degrees?

Comment: Just rotate it three times

Comment: The complexity will be then N^3. Is that not too much? Thanks.

Comment: It's not O(n^3), it's O(n*3), which is just O(n). As far as whether it's "too much," you'll have to test it in your application.

Comment: Thanks. How can I do in place?